# np.random.uniform using random seed generator

Tags: python, numpy, random, seed, astronomy

I want to generate an array of random coordinates with the decimal part randomized within an image with a distance no closer than 40 pixels from each other.

I have only been able to create up to 3400 positions. I would like to generate 5000, but I've let my computer go almost a full day and it doesn't work.

Thank you in advance for your help

```
# generating random positions 

import time
from os import system

start = time.time()

import random
random.seed(3)

num_stars=5000

accepted_x = np.zeros(num_stars)
accepted_y = np.zeros(num_stars)

accepted_x[0] = np.random.uniform(39.786, 4024.713)
accepted_y[0] = np.random.uniform(60.915, 2010.326)

for i in range(1,num_stars): 
    dist = [0]
    
    while np.min(dist) < 40: 
        x_temp = np.random.uniform(39.786, 4024.713)
        y_temp = np.random.uniform(60.915, 2010.326)
        dist = np.sqrt((accepted_x[0:i] - x_temp)**2 + (accepted_y[0:i] - y_temp)**2)
    
    accepted_x[i] = x_temp
    accepted_y[i] = y_temp
         
print('generating artificial stars done! Duration: {} seconds'.format(time.time()-start))
```

Comment: Is there a bound to how large the image can be? If not, perhaps "work your way out" from a center point. You could start with your first generated point being a distance of 40 pixels from the center and use a random increment further from the center and a random radial position.

Comment: yes, the image is on the x-axis (39.786, 4024.713),          and on the y-axis (60.915, 2010.326)

Comment: As an aside, `random.seed(3)` isn't doing anything as you are using numpy's random functions, use `np.random.seed(3)` instead.

Comment: note that requiring your points to have some minimum space between them will represent the distribution of "real stars" worse than a uniform draw.  e.g. look at a photo: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Pleiades_large.jpg where your can see clusters and gaps.  if anything stars are more clustered than uniform, i.e. the opposite of what your code is trying to do

Comment: Sam, thank you for your response. How would you suggest a better distribution of the artificial stars if the purpose is to check that the photometry conducted on original HST images is accurate?

Comment: maybe a [Gaussian process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_process) over the probability of observing a star of some magnitude at given coordinates?

Answer (score 2):

A cartesian grid with a spacing of 40 units will only fit ~4800 stars in the available space of 3960 x 1949, with optimal hexagonal close packing you'll get approximately 5600. So space is getting very tight to fit even 3400 stars in your space. You'd need to be incredibly lucky with your random positioning to fit near to 5000 no matter how long you try for.

Comment: where does 6500 come from?  I get ~5600 via `3960 * 1949 / (pi*20**2/0.907)`, where 0.907 is the approximate [packing density of hexagons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing)

Comment: Yes, that makes more sense, I'll fix the answer